# Selecting different accounts in a mutt send-hook

Tags: email, mutt

I use the instructions outlined [here](https://www.df7cb.de/blog/2010/Using_multiple_IMAP_accounts_with_Mutt.html) to use different accounts in `mutt`. I'd like to be able to select different accounts depending on sender--`send-hook` seems like the right way to go.

`send-hook wife@mydomain.com 'source ~/.mutt/account.personal'`

This works fine to send mail, but if I've done this from my work account, I'm still in my work context (in my work `INBOX`), but `folder`, `imap_user`, `smtp_url` and friends are all set to my personal account. Is there a hook that will fire *after* a mail is sent so I can affect all my work settings?

Comment: I ended up just doing this in different mutt processes in different tmux windows. For me, it's cleaner that way.

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand well what do you want to accomplish. If you want to change variables after changing imap folders, You can use http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#folder-hook